# Best approach to micro photo identification and analysis?

Tags: opencv

I’m working on a market case-study project in which i’m trying to identify and count products in an image passed to the machine learning engine, I’m facing many problems in all approaches i’ve tried / thought of, thus I’m trying to put on a stack of technologies in which each piece will send me bits of information and combined will try to achieve my goal.

Basically these are the problems I’ve faced till now:

1 - When talking about products, I can’t simply identify / match using a logo alone as the product logo itself sometimes has many sub-category products under it; as an example let’s say brand X has sub brands Y and Z, in sub-brand Y alone you can get soup, handwash, etc…

2 - I was against working with HAAR cascade as weighing pros and cons showed me that it won’t be scalable in the long term if decided to go get this project to a professional level, but actually never tried to implement other than the logo, but even HAAR cascade with logo alone wasn’t giving high accuracy in real world testing, is it cause the logo passed is too low (20x20)?

3 - Using FAST I’ve managed to get products interest points and from here I can do maybe counting, slicing, etc… still checking what I can do here, basically I’ve tried FAST and ORB

4 - When tried BFMatching with ORB I’ve faced the same problem in #1, although I’m passing the full shape of the product, it’s matching the logos and deciding that it’s accurate enough, although I want to match full product, I'm thinking of counting (ratio wise) number of interest points which got picked by the matcher

*P.s:*

*- I've looked around for a better place to put this question but found this to be the best, please let me know if I shouldn't.*

*- I can go more technical if needed.*

## Examples:

- points 1 & 4 (product is different but has the same logo):

[image: product is different but has the same logo]

- point 2 (HAAR cascade output - using logo matching - false positives and negatives):

[image: HAAR cascade output - using logo matching - false positives and negatives 1]

[image: HAAR cascade output - using logo matching - false positives and negatives 2]

Comment: Some example images showing what you get and what you expect would be helpful!

Comment: @RickM.  I've edited the question with sample use case

Comment: I would suggest you to try template matching in image pyramid, it should work for the above cases atleast.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'll try it out ...